# Paypal IPN using Classic ASP. TLS1.2

Tags: paypal, asp-classic, paypal-ipn, windows-server-2008-r2, tls1.2

I have a number of clients with old Classic ASP based systems who pass customers through to Paypal to make payment.

Paypal sends an IPN to the site, and the site then makes the necessary response to Paypal to confirm receipt.

My clients have received messages from Paypal recently saying that Paypal is requiring users to use SSL this year.

In our case, that's fine, we've been using SSL all along.

However, Paypal also say that in 2017 they will impose a:

"TLS 1.2 HTTP/1.1 requirement"

I'm not entirely clear, but it looks like this covers the IPN responses my clients site make to Paypal. If so we have a problem.

I can use either the built in MSXML or WinHTTP objects on the Windows server to POST responses to Paypal. However, it looks like only Windows Server 2012 and later will allow posts from these objects using TLS1.2.

All my clients are hosted on Windows Server 2008-r2 shared hosting.

So before I have to start persuading the web hosts to upgrade or search for new hosts, can anyone confirm that the IPN's are definitely covered by this requirement and *will* have to be posted using TLS1.2?

And if that is the case, does anyone have a solution which can be implemented on 2008-r2?

Comment: Not sure 100% sure, but I understand that it will be a PCI requirement to disable old versions of TLS by 2017. Chances are that PayPal will be doing this for all communications, including IPN. You could setup a proxy site that has TLS1.2 that IPN could communicate with, which can then POST to the servers with the older protocols, and let it just sit there in the middle while you get things upgraded.

Comment: All connections **to** Paypal will [require `TLS 1.2/HTTP 1.1` for _production_ in **2017**](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1914&viewlocale=en_US) (it was actually moved from this year, 2016). So for IPN, It's required in the [verification step](https://devblog.paypal.com/upcoming-security-changes-notice/#ipn). For _sandbox_, the requirement is already in place (see first link).. Hth....